# Richardson extrapolation: how to derive an approximation for $f'(x)$ with Euler backward/forward methods

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, extrapolation

We are told that the starting point is the difference
$ f(x+h) - f(x-h) $ (each of which represents it's own series; the last an alternating series) for getting the Richardson extrapolation.

When I do this subtraction the even exponential terms cancel out because of the difference sign while the odd exponential terms ones sum up yielding the following:

$ f(x+h) - f(x-h) = 2hf'(x)+{2h^{3}\over 3!}f'''(x)+... $

So the expression for the derivative yields if i understand it correctly, where now the h's get even exponentials:

$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h} = f'(x) + {h^{2}\over 3!}f'''(x)+...$

Making the stepsize h half as big by replacing every $h$ with $h/2$ in the last expression yields 
(where $4 = 2^2$ and $16 = 2^4$) :

$f'(x) =  \frac{f(x+h/2) - f(x-h/2)}{h} + {h^{2}\over 4*3!}f'''(x)+{h^{4}\over 16*5!}f'''''(x)...$

Now we are supposed to get a series on the form to get an approximation for the derivative:
$f'(x) = \frac{4(f(x+h/2) - f(x-h/2))}{3*h} - \frac{(f(x+h) - f(x-h))}{3*2h} -\frac{1}{4}a_4 h^4 + \frac{5}{16}a_6 h^6 + ...$

Here the a's are constants.

I'm wondering how the numerical values before each term are achieved. The deviation from my result as far as I can see are the numbers above the fractions, and the 2 first terms. I don't really see how to get the last expression, any suggestions?

Comment: Note that $f(x+h) - f(x-h) = 2 hf'(x)+{2h^{3}\over 3!}f'''(x)+...$

Comment: This looks wrong $$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h} = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{h} + {h^{2}\over 4*3!}f'''(x)+{h^{4}\over 16*5!}f'''''(x)...$$ you mention the replacement of $h$ with $h/2$, may be you want to use it in your formula?

Comment: Thx added, typos sneak in when head is warmed up:-)

Comment: should you use fix the last expression as well?

Comment: aah yeah the 1st term in the last expression should now be correct, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$ \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h} = f'(x) + {h^{2}\over 3!}f'''(x)+
{h^{4}\over 5!}f'''''(x)...$$
and 
$$ \frac{f(x+h/2) - f(x-h/2)}{h}= f'(x) + {h^{2}\over 4*3!}f'''(x)+{h^{4}\over 16*5!}f'''''(x)...$$
One write 
$$\frac{4(f(x+h/2) - f(x-h/2))}{3*h} - \frac{(f(x+h) - f(x-h))}{3*2h} = 
\frac{4}{3}
\left(f'(x) + {h^{2}\over 4*3!}f'''(x)+{h^{4}\over 16*5!}f'''''(x) ...\right)-
\frac{1}{3} \left(f'(x) + {h^{2}\over 3!}f'''(x) + {h^{4}\over 5!}f'''''(x) ...\right) =
f'(x) + \frac{4}{3}{h^{4}\over 16*5!}f'''''(x) - \frac{1}{3}{h^{4}\over 5!}f'''''(x)...
=
f'(x)  - \frac{1}{4}{h^{4}\over 5!}f'''''(x)...
$$

Hope this helps.

**Connection to Richardson Extrapolation**

Richardson Extrapolation for a method defined as 
$$A(h)=A_0+Ch^n+o(h^{n+1})$$
is defined as 
$$R(h,k)=\frac{k^nA(h)-A(k h)}{k^n-1}$$
In the question above we have $k=2$, $n=2$ and
 $$A(h)=\frac{f(x+h/2) - f(x-h/2)}{h} + Ch^2...$$

Comment: Thx, I see the relation now. moving the derivative on the other side of the equal sign and equally for the expressions with the (x+h) and (x-h) terms we get what is to be shown. But still the question arises about how one should come up with the ratios 4/3 and 1/3 assuming they are not given since we are to end up with them. Or maybe just a misinterpretation from my side.

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer your question, to get the coefficients you 
evaluate $\frac{k^n}{k^n-1}=\frac{4}3$ and $\frac{1}{k^n-1}=\frac{1}3$

Comment: Thanks, that makes the connections easier to see, so iow there is a recipe we follow and this last part shows the direct relation between our series and the theory..